# Efficiently returning lowest grouped value across 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I'm currently trying to implement a search engine function, trying to return information from 3 tables efficiently. The usage is numeric searches, free text won't be possible and as such I'm not trying to optimise for this scenario.

The tables being used are as follows:

```
Companies hasMany Products
Products hasMany Prices
```

The problem is as follows:

I want to return the single cheapest priced product for each company that meets any specified criteria (this could be criteria against the product or price)

The solution I have is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT Company.id, Company.name AS CompanyName, Product.name, Product.quantity, Price.price
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Price ON Product.id=Price.product_id
LEFT JOIN Company ON Product.company_id=Company.id
/* EXAMPLE CONDITIONS */
WHERE Price.price > 10 AND Product.quantity > 4
ORDER BY Price.price
) AS tmp_table
GROUP BY tmp_table.id
ORDER BY tmp_table.price;
```

**Question:** Is this method of a sub query with joins the most effective way to achieve this solution?

The execution times are ranging anywhere from 1ms to 140ms with 3 companies, each with 3 products, that each have 3 prices so if this were to go into the hundreds it could get messy.

I've created an SQL Fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c194b7/1/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query relies on a "feature" of MySQL that is specifically documented *not* to work.  That is, you are assuming that the extra columns in the outer `group by` come from the first row, and yet the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html) clearly states:

> MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to
>   nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause. This means
>   that the preceding query is legal in MySQL. You can use this feature
>   to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and
>   grouping. However, this is useful primarily when all values in each
>   nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each
>   group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so
>   unless they are the same, the values chosen are **indeterminate**.

I would not recommend the approach you are using.

Because you are using `group by`, you can do this with the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` method:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name AS CompanyName, Product.name,
       substring_index(group_concat(p.name order by pr.price, p.product_id), ',', 1) as price,
       substring_index(group_concat(p.quantity order by pr.price, p.product_id), ',', 1) as price,
       MIN(pr.price) as price
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN
     Price pr
     ON p.id = pr.product_id LEFT JOIN
     Company c
     ON p.company_id = c.id
WHERE pr.price > 10 AND p.quantity > 4
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
ORDER BY pr.price;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I just edited your code slightly to get it to work but it's results are matching what I would expect. I've created a fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c194b7/17/0 with the results/

Comment: I'm not familiar with group_concat()/substring_index() but it seems to still work if I only use this for either ProductName or Quantity which also appears to have a performance impact (unless sql fiddle is just playing up). Would this make a difference? Do I have to use group_concat()/substring_index() for every product/price field I want to display?

Comment: @Alex . . . Well, that is one option.  The other is to grab the appropriate `id`s and join the original tables back in.  However, that requires a subquery, which incurs the overhead of materializing the subquery.

Comment: Thanks again for this after some research I realised what an elegant solution this is!